# Spring cloud Zuul Query parameter encoding

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using Spring cloud zuul proxy to add a query parameter to request.

Therefore a route filter was implemented:

```
@Override
public Object run() {

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    Map<String, List<String>> newParameterMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = context.getRequest().getParameterMap();

    // getting the current parameter
    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String[] values = entry.getValue();
        newParameterMap.put(key, Arrays.asList(values));
    }
    // add new parameter grp
    newParameterMap.put("GRP", Arrays.asList(value));
    context.setRequestQueryParams(newParameterMap);
    return null;
}
```

The request is incoming with iso-8859-1 encoding but changed within Zuul to Utf-8

```
Example:
in: &ORT_BEZ=Geb%E4ude
out: &ORT_BEZ=Geb%EF%BF%BDude
```

This is causing problems in legacy web application which is behind the proxy.

If I use the option "force-original-query-string-encoding= true" in application.properties, the request is passed correctly but query parameter isn`t added.

How can I force zuul to keep query parameter encoding and also add query parameter?

Comment: Did you tried to use the pre filter not the route filter ?

Comment: Yes, already tried this, but it doesn`t changed anything

Comment: what was the order of the pre filter ? did you tried > or < to PREDECORATION (which = 5)

Comment: Tried PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER - 1 and PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER + 1 with no difference